# Не переназначается ViewState

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

```
            if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sort"]) == "Asc")
            {
                dt1.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " Desc";
                ViewState["sort"] = "Desc";
            }
```

Вот код. Первая строка отрабатывает корректно, вторая - никак. Причем у меня не в первый раз ViewState не переназначает свое содержимое. С чем может быть связано подобное поведение? Гугл слишком туманен в этом вопросе.

Comment: Что значит "отрабатывает никак"? ошибка вылетает?

Comment: Значение не становитяся Desc, а продолжает быть ASC

Comment: А клиент вообще получает новый ViewState? Для таких данных лучше делать через HiddenFields.

Comment: каким образом клиент должен получать новый ViewState? И можно подробней идею с HiddenFields?

Comment: Есть контрол HiddenField в котором можно хранить значение но при этом видеть его на клиенте. Viewstate по умолчанию на клиенте закодирован + Viewstate может храниться и на сервере (но не по умолчанию конечно). Не отправляться ViewState может при прямых ajax запросах.

Comment: интересная информация, спасибо